# Dynamically changing header text of a gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi, I am using an ASP `GridView`. I declare one label in `HeaderTemplate` for setting heading of a particular column. How can I dynamically change the header text on a particular button click?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood right, this is what you need,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "The new header";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think on particular button click it will not change you can only change by writing the required code in gridview RowDataBound event